# How to print a List<List<KeyValuepair>?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<List<double>> myList = new List<List<double>>();
        myList.Add(new List<double> { 2D, 2D, 3D, 5D, 8D, 11D, 13D, 13D, 11D, 8D, 5D, 3D });
        myList.Add(new List<double> { 6D, 7D, 10D, 14D, 18D, 21D, 22D, 22D, 19D, 15D, 10D, 7D });

        List<List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>> result = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> r = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();

            for (int j = 0; j < myList[i].Count; j++)
            {

                r.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Values", myList[i][j]));
            }
            result.Add(r);
        }

        foreach(var element in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print the contents of the List 'result'. The above foreach loop is not working. What will be the correct method to print out the list?

Comment: As an aside, adding `D` to every constant is unnecessary. The initializer converts to a bunch of `.Add` calls, `List<double>.Add` takes a `double`, and so any integers are implicitly converted (with no loss of precision, or at least no more than when converting the constants). If you had non-integral constants (like `3.4`) the suffix would still be unnecessary, since `double` is the default.

Comment: Each of your `element` variables in that final foreach loop is a list of keypairvalues. You must iterate over that list as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
foreach(List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> pair in result)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> innerpair in pair)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(innerpair.Key + " " + innerpair.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming data is in memory, you can use LINQ:

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, myList.SelectMany(l => l.ToString()).ToArray());
```

What this does is it flattens the list of lists (`SelectMany` & `ToArray`) while converting values to Strings, then returns a single string with each value in a new line, using `String.Join`.

Make sure you are able to use LINQ by specifying `using System.Linq;` in the appropriate section.

Alternatively you could use `foreach` to iterate over the `SelectMany` result; in this case a single `foreach` would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to nest another foreach in the code which prints to the console, like this:

```
foreach(var element in result) {
       foreach(var el in element) {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: " + el.Key + ", Value: " + el.Value);
       }          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use [KeyValuePair](https://www.dotnetperls.com/keyvaluepair) here:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("one", 1.00));
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("two, 2.00));
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("three", 4.00));

    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
```

or

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> value in values)
 {
    Console.WriteLine($"Pair here: {value.Key}, {value.Value}");
 }
```